# Unable to mock dependency with SpringBoot and Spock Framework

Tags: spring-boot, spock

I'm using SpringBoot 1.5.9, Groovy 2.4.13, Spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4 and Spock-Spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.
I tried following both documentation and a few tutorials on internet:

- http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/module_spring.html
- https://allegro.tech/2018/04/Spring-WebMvcTest-with-Spock.html
- https://objectpartners.com/2018/06/14/spock-1-2-annotations-for-spring-integration-testing/

Below you can see the versions of my test code.

1st version:

```groovy
import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class NotaFiscalControllerIT extends Specification {

  @Unroll
  def "NotaFiscalController::webhook => falha -> Token #cenario" () {

    given:
      notaFiscalService.processarRetornoWebhook(_ as DadoRetornadoDto) >> null

    when:
      def result = this.mvc.perform(
        get('/webhook')
        .header('sec-token', token)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      )

    then:
      result.andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())

    where:
      cenario     | token
      'ausente'   | ''
      'inválido'  | 'blablebli'
  }

  /**********************************************************************/

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mvc

  @SpringBean
  NotaFiscalService notaFiscalService = Mock()

  /**********************************************************************/
}
```

2nd version:

```groovy
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import spock.mock.DetachedMockFactory

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status

@WebMvcTest(controllers = [NotaFiscalController])
class NotaFiscalControllerIT extends Specification {

  @Unroll
  def "NotaFiscalController::webhook => falha -> Token #cenario" () {

    given:
      notaFiscalService.processarRetornoWebhook(_ as DadoRetornadoDto) >> null

    when:
      def result = this.mvc.perform(
        get('/webhook')
        .header('sec-token', token)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      )

    then:
      result.andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())

    where:
      cenario     | token
      'ausente'   | ''
      'inválido'  | 'blablebli'
  }

  /**********************************************************************/

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mvc

  @Autowired
  NotaFiscalService notaFiscalService

  /**********************************************************************/

  @TestConfiguration
  static class MockConfig {
    def detachedMockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

    @Bean
    NotaFiscalService notaFiscalService() {
      return detachedMockFactory.Mock(NotaFiscalService)
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what I do I always get the same Exception:

```
2019-02-06 11:24:09.184 ERROR 6266 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.createMock(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:41) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:42) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockSpringProxyCreator.create(SpockSpringProxyCreator.java:29) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockDefinition.createMock(SpockDefinition.java:75) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.createMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:140) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.registerMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:108) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.register(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:92) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:85) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:78) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:283) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:171) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) [spring-boot-test-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56) [spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:43) [spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:97) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:475) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runInitializer(BaseSpecRunner.java:341) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runInitializer(BaseSpecRunner.java:336) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.initializeAndRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:274) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ParameterizedSpecRunner.runIterations(ParameterizedSpecRunner.java:139) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ParameterizedSpecRunner.runParameterizedFeature(ParameterizedSpecRunner.java:41) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:259) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$5.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:243) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:484) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:467) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:235) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:185) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:95) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$1.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:81) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:484) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:467) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:73) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:64) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.isAvailable()Z
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.determineBestClassLoadingStrategy(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:103) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.access$300(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:27) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:54) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:43) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    ... 54 common frames omitted

2019-02-06 11:24:09.187  INFO 6266 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@36f7d7b: startup date [Wed Feb 06 11:24:06 BRST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-02-06 11:24:09.191 ERROR 6266 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@670002] to prepare test instance [br.com.k21.notafiscal.controller.NotaFiscalControllerIT@283ab206]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56) [spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:43) [spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:97) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:475) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runInitializer(BaseSpecRunner.java:341) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runInitializer(BaseSpecRunner.java:336) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.initializeAndRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:274) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ParameterizedSpecRunner.runIterations(ParameterizedSpecRunner.java:139) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ParameterizedSpecRunner.runParameterizedFeature(ParameterizedSpecRunner.java:41) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:259) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$5.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:243) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:484) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:467) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:235) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:185) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:95) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$1.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:81) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:484) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:467) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:73) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:64) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63) [spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.createMock(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:41) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:42) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockSpringProxyCreator.create(SpockSpringProxyCreator.java:29) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockDefinition.createMock(SpockDefinition.java:75) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.createMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:140) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.registerMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:108) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.register(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:92) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:85) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:78) ~[spock-spring-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:283) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:171) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.isAvailable()Z
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.determineBestClassLoadingStrategy(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:103) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.access$300(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:27) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:54) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:43) ~[spock-core-1.2-groovy-2.4.jar:1.2]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138) ~[byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar:na]
    ... 54 common frames omitted


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:97)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.createMock(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:41)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockSpringProxyCreator.create(SpockSpringProxyCreator.java:29)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockDefinition.createMock(SpockDefinition.java:75)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.createMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:140)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.registerMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:108)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.register(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:92)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:283)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.isAvailable()Z
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.determineBestClassLoadingStrategy(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:103)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory.access$300(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:27)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:54)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ByteBuddyMockFactory.java:43)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    ... 35 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have not actually inspected your code, but I noticed `byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar` in your log. If you use Spock 1.1 or 1.2, maybe you want to upgrade your ByteBuddy version according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564125/1082681). If that works I can turn my comment into an answer, please let me know. I am not sure if that this is the problem at all, so for now it is only a comment in order to eliminate one possible cause.

Comment: I also edited your question in order to add proper code formatting (using indentation, not triple backticks) and syntax highlighting. You have been around here for a while, judging from 500 reputation points. Maybe you should start learning about the mark-up syntax basics used on SO. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much @kriegaex. ByteBuddy was added by SpringFox (which I use to generate swagger documentation) so I was unaware of it's existance and specially that it could interfere in my tests.
Removing it from `testCompile` solved the issue. You can add your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Regarding code formatting I appreciate your feedback. I'll check the basics as you mentioned.

Comment: Done, answer was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not actually inspected your code, but I noticed `byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar` in your log. If you use Spock 1.1 or 1.2, maybe you want to upgrade your ByteBuddy version according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564125/1082681):

- `spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.4` => `byte-buddy:1.8.21`
- `spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4` => `byte-buddy:1.6.5`

Thanks to [*Szymon Stepniak*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194470/szymon-stepniak) who posted the answer I have linked to.

Comment: Thanks, man. For others having the same issue, take a look at the comments under OP.